# Codeigniter Session (User data)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, user-data

I searched on google and found that here at Stack there are several people with similar problems to mine, but none of the answers actually solved my problem. I have an application developed on codeigniter, it uses the library "SESSION" and everything works perfectly, it was my first application using this library. However, I had to make another application very similar to this, so I copied the whole project (renaming it), and modified what was needed. It was then that my problem began ...

Initially when I started the application, the pages were white. both my WAMP is marked to show all the "errors, notices and warnings" and my application is marked as "development", but still nothing was displayed. Googled enough and I saw that I needed the value of $ config ['cookie_domain'] = ""; did it and the application came back to function, however when I did login and was redirected to another page, session data user were lost. I lost so much time trying to solve this problem I decided to rewrite the drivers using native PHP SESSION, but I still wanted to know what happened and how to solve, why not want to stop using the library "SESSION" of codeigniter. Will someone help me?

Important: The problem also occurs when I record the session in the database, it writes the data to the user, however when the page is redirected it creates a new session without user data, so the user can never log

Comment: Have you changed the `$config['encryption_key']` for the new project?

Comment: Yes, I reported a different key for this variable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your browser cookies are enabled. Because code igniter stores even Session to Cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I never do I disable cookies in my browser, and in addition I have tested on multiple browsers

Answer (score 0):

Check the time of your computer and server.

Cookie will be dropped at once if server's time earlier than brower's time

Comment: Did you check time zone? Maybe time/date correct but time zone wrong.

Comment: Debug raw HTTP traffic to see the cookie received and whether sending back to server.

Comment: My php.ini file:
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo

Comment: Please use Chrome or Firefox or any other way to check the HTTP traffic. I think you will see the cookie sent by server, but it will not be sent back to server by your browser